# Checking if a String Contains an IP

Tags: java

How would I go about checking a string contains an ip address?
example
"Hello guys" returns false
"Hello guys here is my ip 22.27.0.0" returns true

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use Regular Expressions http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: first google result for "check if a string contains an ip" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669903/check-to-see-if-a-string-contains-an-ip-address

Comment: Thanks guys! I have been looking for help. Also thanks for welcoming me to stack overflow very nice!

Comment: @PradeepSimha How would you do it without regular expressions? Just curious.

Comment: Marco Acierno that is for C# not for java.

Comment: I thought this was a perfectly reasonable question. I don't know why it got 7 downvotes.

Comment: Simple - SO is not a "write my code" website. It is a site where you can show what your problem is, what kind of research / coding you already did, and *then* ask for help.

Comment: The regex is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Mastering Regular Expressions (Third Edition)* gives a pattern that will validate an IPv4 address, having four dot-separated integers in the range 0-255:

```
^(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.
(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.
(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.
(?:[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$
```

Modifying that to find (rather than validate) an IP, to exclude things that look like IPs turning up within longer strings of dotted digits, and escape backslashes for Java string syntax, we can render it in a Java method as:

```
public static String extractIP(String s) {
    java.util.regex.Matcher m = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(
        "(?<!\\d|\\d\\.)" +
        "(?:[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "(?:[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "(?:[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "(?:[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])" +
        "(?!\\d|\\.\\d)").matcher(s);
    return m.find() ? m.group() : null;
}
```

That will return the IP if one is found in the string, or `null` otherwise.

To check simply if it *contains* an IP, do `if (extractIP(str) != null) ...`.

Comment: I am trying to check if something contains an ip I don't know if there is going to be an ip in the string or not.
EDIT:
sorry I just used a != null check for a boolean thanks man!

Comment: @user3672106 Yes. I thought that a method that extracts an IP might be more generally useful, since you can easily do `!= null` when you only need to test for its presence.

Answer (score 1):

Without using regular expressions, you need two things

- Check when a string is an IP. (IpChecker)
- Check when a string contains an IP  (IpDetector)
- All word in the target string are separated by spaces.

The method is very simple in both cases. Check every part in the strings if correspond to each things.

**Checking when a string is an IP**

If a string is an IP, then is formed by 4 pairs of numbers in the range of 0 - 255.

```
public class IpChecker {

public static boolean isIp(String ip) {

    // Check if the string is not null
    if (ip == null)
        return false;

    // Get the parts of the ip
    String[] parts = ip.split(".");

    if (parts.length != 4)
        return false;

    for (String s : parts) {
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(s);

            // out of range
            if (value <= 0 || value >= 255) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

**Checking when a string contains an IP**
check every word in the string.

```
public class IpDetector {

    // Detects an Ip given a phrace
    public static String detect(String ip) {

        // Check if the string is not null
        if (ip == null)
            return null;

        // Get the parts of the ip
        String[] parts = ip.split(" ");

        for (String part : parts) {
            if (IpParser.isIp(part)) {
                return part;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is a very simple idea that you can improve it.